# Job requirement problem

Tags: job-description

So I work at a zoo and am in Union. My buddy bid on a horticultural position opening. The job description requirements were associates in horticulture OR relative work experience OR bachelors in biology. My buddy has bachelors in biology but they are saying sorry the really want the other to as an applicant. No one else bid on this job; how can they deny this? Thanks

Comment: I guess the zoo does not like your buddy's resume or profile in some way. So, they just find a general (and fake) excuse that is "We prefer other candidates whose profiles fit the job requirements better" even if they don't have any other job applicants. This kind of excuse to reject a candidate happens in many companies in various industries.

Comment: Just because your friend has a degree in Biology, doesn't mean they were (or are) the best candidate... Meeting the requirements doesn't mean they *have* to give you the job. They are free to hold this position open as long as necessary to get the candidate they want.

Comment: So normally yes, but not in a union. If he bid on the job and meets requirements then he should be awarded the position. Their excuse is that the posting should of said AND not OR when it came to requirements.

Comment: And people wonder why unions are considered a bad thing. No intelligence in hiring, just a set of tickyboxes for people to meet, and genuine mistakes in job specs being used as an excuse to make trouble.

Comment: the union isn't doing the hiring; they dont make the employer hire anyone. they just make sure there is fairness with new positions in that the current union employees get first crack. An employer can easily get around things with proper requirements. It's not like they dont already have everyones resumes on file lol. I dont know why people think that; good pay, pension, benefits, paid vacations, holiday pay. They just make sure everything gets done based on seniority.

Answer (score 6):

Because they don't have to hire anyone; job description requirements are "necessary" not "sufficient" requirements. Often the right choice when given a list of candidates is "find someone else", particularly if the list of candidates is short.

Comment: In a non union situation sure; but this is a union situation where Inter department bids, then company wide, then union hall, then anyone can apply. So for anyone to apply and be hired the previous situations have to produce no qualified current employees who’ve bid. that’s my issue; he is but they are somehow trying to get out of it

Answer (score 0):

Rejecting someone is always difficult and when it’s necessary to provide a reason for the rejection, it’s a lot easier to give a simple, matter-of-fact explanation than to give the actual reasons. Why they didn’t hire your friend is anyone’s guess and there could be some truth in them saying they’d prefer someone with a horticulture degree and/or work experience but it’s probably not the only reason or even the most important reason.

Sometimes, through no fault of our own, we rub people the wrong way and leave a bad impression. It’s not so much a problem to be solved or a wrong that needs to be corrected. It’s simply the nature of life.

Comment: So the problem is that it shouldn’t be a whole bunch of applications and they get to choose. It’s a union position posted so anyone can bid on it in the union. And whoever meets the qualifications and has most seniority is then awarded the bid. They are trying to say he doesn’t meet their requirements when he does based on the posting.